# Will gradle run Tests annotated with @NotThreadSafe run as a single test process at a time

Tags: java, gradle, junit, parallel-testing

We have currently set up our application set up with Junit 4 and Maven with the surefire plugin.
Now we are migrating to gradle and we want to run the test case in parallel with the exception of the ones annotated with `@NotThreadSafe`. Given the long running nature of our test cases it is hard to find out if they are running in parallel or not.
Has anybody used the `@NotThreadSafe` annotation together with gradle?

In [the gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html) I wasn't able to find out if it is supported or not.